# Override an object from array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object as below:

```
let arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jill',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  }
];
```

I want to update an object with id = 1 with some properties from another object.

```
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'JOHn1'
}
```

The expected out is:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'JOHn1',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jill',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  }
]
```

I tried using Object.assign(), but it does not work. Could anyone please let me know.

```
arr = Object.assign(arr, obj);
```

thanks

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the entry which you want to use as the assign target first: in this case, you need to query for the entry where `id` is `1`. This can be done by using [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to locate the target, and then do `Object.assign()` on the target itself.

Since the found object is pass-by-reference, updating the object directly will update its entry in your array of objects directly.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jill',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  }
];

const obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'JOHn1'
};

const foundObj = arr.find(({ id }) => id === obj.id);
if (foundObj) {
  Object.assign(foundObj, obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```